# How can I generate non-repeated possible combinations of a set of characters in an array?

Tags: combinations

How to generate ordered combinations for an array of characters?

For example, given an array `['a','b','c','d']`, write a program for all possible combinations ordered ascendingly by length, then ascendingly by lexicographic order - in other words:

```
ab ac ad bc bd cd abc abd acd bcd abcd
```

Comment: This sounds like homework or a hacker challenge.  Regardless, what have you tried, and what specific issue do you have?  Also, in what programming language are you trying to solve this problem?

Comment: Its not homework or hacker challenge. I am trying to get all combinations of array elements. You can use any language of your choice.

Comment: "I am trying to get all combinations of array elements". If so the elements would be 
aa ab ac ad ba bb bc bd ca cb cc cd ....etc etc
instead of 
ab ac ad bc bd cd abc abd acd bcd abcd

Comment: Yeah but the combination needs to be in lexicographic order as @J0e3gan suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Although I have written it in Console application, by changing static void Main(string[] args) into a method it works.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Dictionary<string, int> s = new Dictionary<string, int>();
     Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
     bool bln = false;
     string[] str = new string[5] { "a", "b", "c", "d","e"};
     int len = str.Length;
     string lastWord = "";
     // a,b,c,d - count=1, aa,ab,ac,ad,ba,bb,bc,bd - count=2 etc
     int count = 1;
     foreach(string sa in str)
     {
         dict.Add(sa,1);
     }

     for(int m=0;m<len;m++)
     {
         // Gets last word as eeeee in this example             
         lastWord += str[4];
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
     {
         foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in dict)
         {
              for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
              {
                   if (kvp.Value == count)
                   {                          
                       s.Add(kvp.Key + str[j],count + 1);
                       // If last combination has reached
                       if (s.Keys.Contains(lastWord))
                          bln = true;
                   }
              }
         }                
         foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in s)
         {
             if (kvp.Value == count + 1)
             {
                 dict.Add(kvp.Key,kvp.Value);
             }
         }
         if (bln)
            break;
         count++;
         // a,b,c,d - 4 combinations. aa,ab,ac,ad,ba,bb,bc,bd...4*4=16, then 64 etc
         len = len * str.Length;
     }
     dict.Clear();
     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in s)
     {
          string s1 = SortWord(kvp.Key);
          if(!dict.Keys.Contains(s1))
               dict.Add(s1, kvp.Value);               
     }       
     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in s)
     {
         // abdc will get sorted to abcd
         string s1 = SortWord(kvp.Key);
         // If aabc then false becz 'a' is repeated two times
         bool b = IsWordsRepeat(s1);
         if (dict.Keys.Contains(s1) && !b)
         {                  
              dict.Remove(SortWord(kvp.Key));                    
         }
     }
     Console.ReadLine();  
}
```

Gets a boolean status to check whether a character is repeated more than 1 time

```
public static bool IsWordsRepeat(string text)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach(char c in text)
    {
         count = 0;
         foreach (char c1 in text)
         {
              if (c == c1)
              {
                  count++;
              }
              if (count == 2)
                 return false;
         }
    }
    return true;  
}
```

Get word after sorting(ie, abdc to abcd)

```
static string SortWord(string str)
{
    char[] chars = str.ToArray();
    Array.Sort(chars);
    return new string(chars);
}
```

You will get your results in dict at last in the sorted manner.

**RESULT**

According to your question you had asked to order the string like

```
ab ac ad bc bd cd abc abd acd bcd abcd
```

which is not in alphabetical/lexicographic order and which forms the result as follows

[image]

And as of now you are required to order in another order. Just add the below code before Console.ReadLine() which generates your desired result

```
var list = dict.Keys.ToList();
list.Sort();
foreach (var key in list)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", key);
}
```

which shows the below result

[image]

Comment: I have added comments. Is it enough for this answer? @leppie

Comment: Did u try the above code? Got the solution? @Prasad Nair

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class combPowerSet {

     //printing the charachters as per the number sent.
     void printNumber(int number, char [] items)
        {
            String digitString = Integer.toString(number);
            char [] digitStringArray = digitString.toCharArray();
            int length = digitStringArray.length;
            for ( int i=0; i<length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(items[Character.getNumericValue(digitStringArray[i])-1]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    //checking if the number follows the required pattern.
    boolean checkCondition(int number, int itemSize)
    {
        boolean validNumber = true;
        String digitString = Integer.toString(number);
        char [] digitStringArray = digitString.toCharArray();
        int length = digitStringArray.length;
        for ( int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            for( int j = i+1; j < length; j++)
            {
                int x = Character.getNumericValue(digitStringArray[i]);
                int y = Character.getNumericValue(digitStringArray[j]);             

                if (x > itemSize-1 || y > itemSize || x > y  || x==y)
                {
                    validNumber = false;
                    break;
                }               
            }
            if (validNumber == false) break;
         }
        return validNumber;     
    }


    void printCombinations(char [] items)
    {
        double maxDigit = 0; 
        int itemSize = items.length;
        for(int i=1; i<=itemSize; i++)
        {
            maxDigit = maxDigit + i*Math.pow(10,itemSize-i);
        }


        for(int x=12; x<=maxDigit; x++)
        {
            if(checkCondition(x, itemSize))
            {
                printNumber(x, items);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        char [] arr = { 'a','b', 'c','d', 'e'};
        combPowerSet obj = new combPowerSet();
        obj.printCombinations(arr);     

    }
 }
```

Comment: Show your output @Prasad Nair